# How do I get Firebase array values with Plugin.CloudFirestore?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I have a Firebase document with an `array` field which holds `reference` values.

I'm using [Plugin.CloudFirestore](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore) and I'm trying to get all the references from the database in order to access the referenced documents with the following code:

```
public class myDoc
{
   public List<IDocumentReference> myArray { get; set; }
}

var getMyDoc = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                                        .Instance
                                        .Collection("myCollection")
                                        .Document("userId")
                                        .GetAsync();

var myRefs = getMyDoc.ToObject<myDoc>().myArray;

List<IDocumentSnapshot> referencedDocs = null;

foreach (var myRef in myRefs)
{
   var doc = await myRef.GetAsync();
   referencedDocs.Add(doc);
}
```

I would expect to get all the referenced docs listed in the `referencedDocs` list, but that's not the case.
I suspect that the `List<IDocumentReference>` data type is wrong. What would be the correct one? Or should I adopt an entirely different approach?

edit:

In debugging mode I can see that the `myRefs` variable for each element of the array has many fields with different values. For example for position [0]:

`'Firestore {Plugin.CloudFirestore.FirestoreWrapper} = Plugin.CloudFirestore.FirestoreWrapper'`

`Id = "firstReferencedId"   of type string`

`Parent = {Plugin.CloudFirestore.CollectionReferenceWrapper}    Plugin.CloudFirestore.CollectionReferenceWrapper`

`Path = "myCollection/firstReferencedId"    of type string`

By the way, also the `myRef` variable seems to remain stuck at the same value. And the `referencedDocs` list remains `null`.

Comment: Does myRefs contain an array of data as expected?  Does the foreach loop execute?  As written this code will not work because referencedDocs is never initialized and will always be null

Comment: No, `myRefs` remains empty. I should have made that clear in my post... I suspect the reason is that `List<IDocumentReference>` is the wrong data type.
The `foreach` executes with no errors.

Comment: If myRefs is empty the for loop won’t do anything.  What does GetMyDoc  contain?

Comment: Well, I have to retract my previous post. I was looking at the wrong variable! myRefs returns the contents of the array, but the path field of the variable is of type `string`. Is that type right?

Comment: I have no idea what “the path field of the variable” means.  Please [edit] your post to include the relevant info

Comment: Just made an edit. I think the problem lies with the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Ok, what debugging have you done to test that theory?

Comment: I have set a breakpoint at `referencedDocs.Add(doc);` and I'm checking the values of the variables in the Locals window of VS. `myRef` and `doc` seem to have the same value each time I click "Continue" for the loop to repeat another iteration. `referencedDocs` stays null all the time, even after the completion of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: You can’t add anything to a null collection.  You have to initialize it first, otherwise it will throw a NullRef exception

Comment: Initialize it with what value? Should I assign to it a random doc from the database? By the way no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: OK. I got it. `List<IDocumentSnapshot> referencedDocs = List<IDocumentSnapshot>();` No need to add anything during initialization.

Comment: `referencedDocs = new List<IDocumentSnapshot>();`. This is basic C#

Comment: Yeah, I know. I thought there was the need to also add elements, but an empty List also works fine for the Add...

Comment: Does [this article](https://medium.com/@t.masonbarneydev/iterating-asynchronously-how-to-use-async-await-with-foreach-in-c-d7e6d21f89fa) about using async await in foreach helpful to you ? Try using async await in foreach as follows: `await foreach (var myRef in myRefs)`

Comment: @RohitKharche I don't know. Is it necessary to use await for the `foreach` loop? I use it inside its body `var doc = await myRef.GetAsync();` and everything works fine. I have no issues with the code I use right now.

Comment: can you post the answer if your issue is solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class myDoc
{
   public List<IDocumentReference> myArray { get; set; }
}

var getMyDoc = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                                        .Instance
                                        .Collection("myCollection")
                                        .Document("userId")
                                        .GetAsync();

var myRefs = getMyDoc.ToObject<myDoc>().myArray;

List<IDocumentSnapshot> referencedDocs = new List<IDocumentSnapshot>(); // This is the correct line.

foreach (var myRef in myRefs)
{
   var doc = await myRef.GetAsync();
   referencedDocs.Add(doc);
}
```

The problem with the original code was that the `referencedDocs` `List` was not initialized but set to `null`. For the `Add` method to work initialization is obligatory as [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) suggested.